# Importing custom packages in golang

Tags: go

I have the following:

```
app/main.go
app/server/server.go
app/server/templates.go
```

`main.go` has an import statement of `import "app/server"`, but when compiled, it complains about:

`found packages server (server.go) and templates (templates.go) in app/server`

Im guessing it is confused about which package to load up? My intention is that `server.go` will setup the routes and import `./templates.go` to render templates.

Is there a better way to layout files? Should I move `templates.go` to it's own directory?

Comment: You can't define two packages in one directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this: http://golang.org/doc/code.html — but in short:

- One package per directory/one directory per package. You have both `server` and `templates` packages where you should just have one - `package main` if you are attempting to compile a binary and not a library.
- Don't use "relative" imports. Use the fully qualified path - i.e. if your base project is `$GOPATH/src/github.com/JohnFromSO/myapp` then you would import sub-packages as `github.com/JohnFromSo/myapp/database`.
- You probably don't need to split out `templates.go` into a separate package - a good rule of thumb is "would this package be usable if it stood on its own/usable by others?"

Another good read is https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091

Comment: Thanks for the resource. If I had to have multiples files in a package, how do you load them within the main package file?

Comment: @John You don't need to—files in the same package share the same namespace. `server.go` can call the functions in `templates.go` or `handlers.go` when they're all part of the same package.

The only "file specific" part of Go is the way imports are handled: the imports at the top of each file reflect just that file (mostly so you don't have to update every import block in a larger project when you add/remove one thing).